# How do I merge (insert) rows from one dataframe into another one in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose I have a following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'val': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
```

I want to **modify** the column `val` with values from another dataframes like these:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2, 3], 'val': [1, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 5], 'val': [2, 2]})
```

I need a function `merge_values_into_df` that would work in the way to provide the following result:

```
df = merge_values_into_df(df1, on='id', field='val')
df = merge_values_into_df(df2, on='id', field='val')
print(df)


   id  val
0   1    2
1   2    1
2   3    1
3   4    0
4   5    2
```

I need an efficient (by CPU and memory) solution because I want to apply the approach to huge dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with convert `id` to index in all DataFrames:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
df2 = df2.set_index('id')

df.update(df1)
df.update(df2)

df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   id  val
0   1  2.0
1   2  1.0
2   3  1.0
3   4  0.0
4   5  2.0
```

Comment: To get better performance I would recommend `df.set_index('id', inplace=True)` instead of `df = df.set_index('id')`, because it does not create a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can `concat` all dataframes and `drop_duplicated` same id by keeping the last occurrence of id.

```
out = pd.concat([df, df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
print(out.sort_values('id', ignore_index=True))

# Output
   id  val
0   1    2
1   2    1
2   3    1
3   4    0
4   5    2
```

Comment: I think it seems too consuming because `pd.concat([df, df1, df2])` creates a copy of all data in the dataframes. But the idea is great. Thank you.